# My Tkinter scrolled table shifts when scrolling starts; I want it to start flush left

Tags: python, tkinter, scroll, tkinter-canvas

I'm partly using code I got elsewhere, and as I'm still only moderately experienced in Python and less so in tkinter, I may need help with both.

This question and the files are available as a [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/kogorman/7c6a621fcaaf3ac1e53de821de5a8f52), so I won't post the code twice.

The main oddity is that a scrolled table (gridded frame in a canvas with scrollbars) starts out centered but when enough rows exist for vertical scrolling to start, it suddenly shifts flush left.  I'd like it to stop jumping around like that.

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Take the time to create a [mcve] and include it in your question. 600+ lines of code is about 15x more code that anyone is going to want to wade through.

Comment: Don't post the code twice, no. But do post a working example of what you're having an issue once.

Comment: _" reduce the code until it's small enough to wrap my brain around it and maybe I'll see the problem myself"_ - yes, that is the #1 reason to create the [mcve]. Often, the very act of doing that exposes the error. Being able to do this will serve you for your entire career, it's not just a tool for beginners.

Comment: I can't run it because it needs file `tables3`. Is this your file or some module?

Comment: tables3 is also in the gist,

Comment: I tried to make a smaller example.  It's really hard to do.  Getting a scrolled and mutable table is just plain complicated and there's no way it's gonna be 600/15=40 lines or even close.  I guess what I was hoping for was that someone familiar with this stuff would recognize the kind of problem I was having and would know where to look.  If no answer comes forward, I may come back to this later and try again to simplify.